# How create a project in Django path

Tags: django

I would like create my first project in Django. I have installed Python (Version 3.7.2) and Django (Version 3.1.2).

In my PC I run a command `py -m django startproject mysite`, however there is no mysite file in C:\Users\misak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python . The mysite file has been created in C:\Users\misak . How can I create mysite file by default in C:\Users\misak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python , please?

Because than I want to run the sever using a command `py manage.py runserver`, which is not possible now, because of an error

"C:\Users\misak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you are creating a project this way
Generally, i follow this steps:

1 - create a folder (in your case in C:\Users\misak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python)

2 - navigate to that folder using terminal (cd AppData\Local\Programs\Python\your_folder_name)

3 - run "python -m venv venv" in terminal to create a virtual environment

4 - run "venv\Scripts\activate" to activate virtual environment

5 - pip install django

6 - django-admin startproject 'project_name' . (observe the .)

Answer (score 0):

you created a project on the directory you ran the command.
Then what you need to do is to enter this directory with `cd mysite`. If you `ls` or if you just open the directory with the windows navigator you would see some files, one of them should be `manage.py`. if you run `py manage.py runserver` inside this diriectory, it should work, given that the py executable is in your path. This guide is useful: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/